# API fetching didn't work after I deployed

Tags: reactjs, deployment, react-hooks, vercel

I deployed my React web work as a test at Vercel but the API didn't work and my web now is Empty..
my project and api works perfectly in my localhost !
some one knows why ?

my empty web :-
https://web-3-0-prokect-1.vercel.app/

api code in the useEffect hook:-
https://github.com/Adelndf/web.3.0-prokect-1/blob/master/src/App.js

by the way im new in coding so some of my coding words or terms might be little bit weird :)
hopefully someone understand my issue here

Comment: you have a CORS Error which basically means you API call needs to happen over a server request. You can use express, next.js and various other solutions to rewrite it quick..

Answer (score 0):

Your API request is not successful because of CORS error. This usually won't be an issue when you try in localhost. To learn more about CORS, click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors).

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it with the easy way cuz at the end its just a testing project..
the solution if any one needed it is :-

i added ( https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ ) before my api ulr and it works..

u can see it in github link at the top